# Execute a SQL stored proc from a SQL view

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I am finding that calling a stored proc in Excel is not as easy as it should be, but calling a view, or a direct table is very easy. So, how can I create a view that will call a stored proc with no params?

I know I won't be able to pass any values into the view, and I don't need or want to, Just want to wrap a stored proc in a view.

something like `select exec MyStoredProc()` would be great.

Comment: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/11/26/select-columns-from-exec-procedure-name-is-this-possible.aspx

Answer (score 11):

iirc (I don't have a copy to hand) if you happen to be in T-SQL it should be possible to select * from a **user defined table function** (which are for most intents and purposes identical to sprocs) which returns a table variable.

Comment: This is a great solution and avoids the security issues that Russ is worried about.

Comment: Typicaly I would go for this option, but the stored proc in question is the top of several nested stored proc's and converting them all to functions isn't a realistic option in this specific case. 

In this case, I have several nested stored procs, that perform several xpath queries.

Comment: yeah here's hoping he notices :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put a trigger on a dummy table, and call the proc inside the trigger.

This is definitely a hack, and you would want to really lock down permissions on the table and proc.

Comment: But could you then return the results of the trigger (assuming that is what Russ wants)?

Comment: Here's one scenario where I would need to use a view.

In LINQ to Entities, the process to map a result set from a stored procedure to a custom entity requires that you manually update the .edmx file, which is not good because the changes get lost each time you update the model from the database.

So, it would be nice to map the result set to a view.