# Can I dynamically call a stored procedure from a view?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql, sql-view

Specifically, can I call a proc from the *current database* in a view.  I already know about the [openrowset hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349979/execute-a-sql-stored-proc-from-a-sql-view), so this works, for example:

```
create view MyView as
    select *
    from openrowset (
        'sqloledb',
        'server=(local);trusted_connection=yes;',
        'exec MyDatabase.dbo.MyStoredProcedure' -- Works fine
    )
```

But I'd like to be able to call the proc from the current DB without hard-coding the name like so:

```
create view MyView as
    select *
    from openrowset (
        'sqloledb',
        'server=(local);trusted_connection=yes;',
        'exec ' + db_name() + '.dbo.MyStoredProcedure' -- Don't want to hard-code DB name
    )
```

This doesn't work, unfortunately, as openrowset expects literal strings, rather than variables of any sort.

Regardless of security and performance considerations, is there a workaround?  It would make the maintenance of a legacy system much more bearable, as the proc that this view will call connects to a different database depending upon environment (dev, test, prod).

Comment: Nope, you can't call a stored procedure

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Stored Procedure in a View?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916784/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-a-view)

Comment: Well, you can using openrowset. It's a bit of a hack and, admittedly, I'm looking for an even bigger hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use dynamic SQL in a view. You could just create three views if there are only three different "environments", and/or use synonyms depending on the environment. So for example, you could have three views (pseudo/trimmed):

```
create view dbo.devMyView as
    select * ... 'exec Dev.dbo.MyStoredProcedure'
go
create view dbo.testMyView as
    select * ... 'exec Test.dbo.MyStoredProcedure'
go
create view dbo.prodMyView as
    select * ... 'exec Prod.dbo.MyStoredProcedure'
```

Then you can use dynamic SQL in your code to specify which view you want, or you can drop and create a synonym when you want to simulate each environment, e.g.

```
DROP SYNONYM dbo.MyView;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.MyView FOR dbo.devMyView;
```

Now the code that references dbo.MyView will ultimately call the stored procedure in the dev database. The downside of this is that only one synonym can be active/redirecting at any given time.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. Synonyms are an interesting alternative in this case...looks like I'll be creating them dynamically with a post-deployment script.