# How to create table from stored procedure return?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Microsoft SQL Server R2 2008. And i see it first time in my life.
I have a SP:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @Id uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @Segment_ID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @SDate datetime
DECLARE @EDate datetime
DECLARE @withBig bit
DECLARE @withKm bit
DECLARE @withGeo bit
DECLARE @withDescr bit


DECLARE @BusStationCursor CURSOR
SET @BusStationCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT Id, Segment_ID, E_Date_Begin, E_Date_Begin
FROM BusStation

OPEN @BusStationCursor
FETCH NEXT    FROM @BusStationCursor INTO @ID, @Segment_ID, @SDate, @EDate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

EXECUTE @RC = [dd_ugra].[dbo].[Request_BusStation] 
  @Id
  ,@Segment_ID
  ,@SDate
  ,@EDate
  ,@withBig=1
  ,@withKm=1
  ,@withGeo=1
  ,@withDescr=1


FETCH NEXT    FROM @BusStationCursor INTO @ID, @Segment_ID, @SDate, @EDate
END
CLOSE @BusStationCursor
DEALLOCATE @BusStationCursor
GO
```

But i have a static information so i dont want to call sp each time when i want to see data, how to create table using sp result?

**UPDATE**

So i have a sp what returns some columns. I can use sp to create view. I cant post sp becouse its really huge.

Comment: A view is not a static table of results that you can just look at. It's simply a query that returns information stored in the actual tables of the database.

Comment: Maybe if you show us the code of your sp we can help you get around the need for a cursor

Comment: @Lamak: sp huge i cant post it. This sp calling for each row. I just need in example what shows how to use procedure result to create view.

Comment: Well, as @Greg said, you can't. The best you can do would be to create a table with the columns and data types that match the result of your sp, and then inserting those results into that table.

Comment: @Lamak: Its sad. But okey. How to create table using sp result?

Comment: What are you trying to return? The list of RC values?

Comment: @Love@Learn: Its something about 30 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can potentially [call a procedure from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349979/execute-a-sql-stored-proc-from-a-sql-view):

```
create view MyView as
    select *
    from openrowset (
        'sqloledb',
        'server=(local);trusted_connection=yes;',
        'exec MyDatabase.dbo.MyStoredProcedure'
    )
```

Note that you'd have to hard-code any parameters, or else return all records possible from the proc (may have to change proc) and filter with a where clause in the view definition or the outer query (views don't take parameters, they take where clauses).

Also, you could have your view simply be the definition of the cursor:

```
SELECT Id, Segment_ID, E_Date_Begin, E_Date_Begin
FROM BusStation
```

and then again use a where clause in the outer query. This would assume that the cursor and logic in the proc don't actually change the data, which is probably a long shot (why else would it need a cursor?).

Beyond this, you'll have to understand exactly what the proc is doing to determine if you can make a query (view) which does the same thing.  Obviously, the SE community can't assist in this effort without the full code of the proc and possibly any other procs/functions/triggers/views that the proc may call.

Comment: Sorry im not good wiht sql so i ask some stupid questions. Code snippet what i write in question its just a calling of sp, right? So i can use it in `openrowset`? Becouse i dont understand how procedure calling in your example.

Comment: @KliverMax as an example, try replacing `exec MyDatabase.dbo.MyStoredProcedure` with `exec master.dbo.sp_who` and run it.  Do you understand what is happening now?